# is this the correct open cover to show this topological space is not compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

For the following space $(X
, \tau)$, find an open cover C of X that does not contain a finite
subcover (proving that $(X
, \tau)$ is not compact). Try to find a minimal one.

$X = \mathbb{Q}\cap [0, 1], \tau = \{U \cap [0, 1] \cap\mathbb{Q} |U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ open in the standard topology$\}$

So what I was thinking is that $U \cap [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is the same as $[0,1] \cap\mathbb{Q}$ because every time there is an intersection of $U$,$\mathbb{Q}$ and $[0,1]$ it must be a rational number between $[0,1]$. Then the open cover we seek would be $C= \{(0,1) \cap\mathbb{Q}\}$.

Could someone please tell me if this is correct ?

Comment: You don't have an open cover of $X$. You have a single set which doesn't cover the endpoints. Even if it did cover the endpoints, it is certainly a finite cover, so that won't do.

Comment: **Hint:** Consider an increasing sequence of irrationals $0<x_0<x_1<\cdots$ converging to an irrational $x<1$. The complement of this sequence in $X$ is a countable set of disjoint intervals open in $X$, and these intervals cover $X$.

Comment: @MPW I thought the rationals between zero and one were infinite ?

Comment: @jamiemma1995 A finite cover means a cover containing a finite number of sets. Your cover, $C$, is one set. That set may be infinite, but the cover is finite.

Comment: "Finite subcover" means you only need finitely many *sets*, not that the sets themselves are finite sets.

Comment: I think the cover is C={U∩[0,1]∩x|U⊆R open in the standard topology,x is irrational}, is this correct ? or would the cover simply be C:={q|q∈{Q} ∩ [0, 1]}

Comment: @exodius.  Intersecting with a number is meaningless.

Comment: Let r be an irrational in the space.  Find an open cover of [0,r) that has no finite subcover.